# Netbeans and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

For some reason when I create a project in netbeans and go to run the project it also loads the xxamp index file and not the project index file that is apart of the codeigniter installation.

http://screencast.com/t/qOSH80wPgvf

**Edit:**

Here is my file tree I have right now set up for my project. Why Netbeans creates an important files folder I have no idea for my CI project. I have edited the index file to have the application and system variable to both have the ../system or applicaton as its value. I have changed the Web Root inside the project properties to have a value of public_html and I have also changed the value of the Index File field to say index.php.

After doing this and running the project I would expect to get the default Welcome to Codeigniter page and I don't. I am receiving a message that shows the following. Any ideas on why this is?

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16 

Projects
- MyFirstProject
    - Source Files
        - application
        - public_html
            - assets
            index.php
        - system
    - Test Files
    - Important Files
    - Include Path
```

I've tried doing some additional research on the topic and have yet to come up with a solution.

**Edit 2:**

Any ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely related to your choice of folder layout. Which I assume you do, for "security reasons". That said, NetBeans isn't a server. Its an IDE, so you can't manipulate it the same way you would the server.

Most servers by default define your "root" folder as "public_html" or "www" as far as where it looks by default to serve files for public consumption. Through the use of PHP you can tell the index.php that comes with CodeIgniter to look up one directory outside of the defined root and have it read the file(s) accordingly.

However, to setup a project in netbeans and have all files and folder accounted for accordingly you need to tell it that all your files start in whatever folder they reside. So it can load all the files and read from them respectively. This in essence and in respect to server logic is telling it that the folder that houses

```
application
public_html
system
```

is the define root path. So inadvertantly by breaking out of the design of codeigniter and placing the core files outside of what would be your defined root on the server is breaking your project. There is not an index.php depicted in your listing above at the same level that those folders are in. If there is, its the index.php for xxamp that keeps loading for you by default.

What you need to do is stop trying to implement your "security measures" and put them in the right order. Or.. not include that folder in your project telling it the one with assets and index.php is the root path. If netbeans is smart enough it will find the files and folders outside like the server will.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project and go to properties. Make sure that in the run configuration the URL is correct and the index file is properly set up and matches your directory in xxamp.

Answer (score 1):

after downloading codeigniter open index.php file and there set your path correctly to your
application folder because i think you putted your index.php inside public_html folder so
the path which is set by default in index.php is not working and can not find application folder, try to fix it and it will work fine your problem is not with netbeans.